# CD40109 level shifter is not working

Tags: level-shifting

I've designed a hardware using [CD40109](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd40109b-q1.pdf?ts=1687881079455) level shifter.
The following shows schematics.
I designed PCB and built PCBA prototype.
However, it is not working as expected.

When I am giving 3.3V to `OUT_CTL1`, I expected the `OUT_CTL1HV` will output 12V.
But it was 0V. It was same on the other channel `OUT_CTL2` - `OUT_CTL2HV`.
What could be wrong in my design?

[image: CD40109 Level Shifter Schematics]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-check your physical board wiring. You have two different 3.3 V nets, one is named `3V3P` and the other `3V3`. If this is the case with the physical board, then one of the nets may be isolated from the other, and may not be receiving power as expected.

In other words, if `3V3P` is actually powered, then the enable pins for inputs C and D are not receiving 3.3 V because they are not connected to the same net as VCC. (Unless you have something not shown that connects them.)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. On the board, 3V3P is the peripheral power controlled by microcontroller, which is powered off in sleeping mode. 3V3 is always-on voltage for microcontroller. I thought both would be on, but I'll check it on board again.

Comment: That's all I can find between your schematic and the datasheet. Measure everything and try to swap out aspects of the design (e.g. try a different CD40109 in case you have a dead IC; try to supply 3V3 to an input pin directly without the microcontroller; etc.)

Comment: You were right. 3V3P was not connected anywhere. The design had gone through many revisions and I forgot that I removed 3V3P supply part as I thought it's not more needed. Thank you a lot!